# Balanced Payments PHP Client: query result triggers uncaught exception

Tags: php, exception, balanced-payments

I'm trying to query a marketplace for an account that matches an e-mail address, and when it can't find a result, it's raising an uncaught exception despite my try/catch block.

```
try {
    $vendor = $this->marketplace ->accounts ->query()
               ->filter(Balanced\Account::$f->email_address->eq($this->vendor['email']))
               ->one();
    $this->balanced_vendor = $vendor; 
    return true;
} catch (Balanced\Exceptions\HTTPError $e) {
    $this->notify('no-vendor', $e);
}
```

What might i be doing wrong ?

Thanks !

Comment: What specific exception class is thrown, what message does it provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the [`Balanced\Core\Query`](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-php/blob/master/src/Balanced/Core/Query.php#L8) class throws both [`Balanced\Exceptions\MultipleResultsFound`](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-php/blob/master/src/Balanced/Exceptions/MultipleResultsFound.php#L9) and [`Balanced\Exceptions\NoResultFound`](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-php/blob/master/src/Balanced/Exceptions/NoResultFound.php#L8) from its [`one()`](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-php/blob/master/src/Balanced/Core/Query.php#L127) method, not [`Balanced\Exceptions\HTTPError`](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-php/blob/master/src/Balanced/Exceptions/HTTPError.php#L12).

To fix your immediate problem, you should change your `catch` directive to:

```
} catch (Balanced\Exceptions\MultipleResultsFound $e) {
    // handle multiple results..
} catch (Balanced\Exceptions\NoResultsFound $e) {
    $this->notify('no-vendor', $e);
}
```

From the looks of it though, you attempted to use the [`Balanced\Exceptions\HTTPError`](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-php/blob/master/src/Balanced/Exceptions/HTTPError.php#L12) as a catch all, which can be considered a lacking feature of the client. What I've done, is I've filed a [Github issue](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-php/issues/1) for you that suggest all exceptions inherit from a base Balanced exception.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This was fixed in version 0.6.5 of the balanced-php client.